# RenderSection from partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In `_Layout.cshtml` file I have such method `@RenderSection("head", false)`.

In **partial** view `UploadForm.cshtml` I have code below.

When I run web app the `head` section is not rendered. How to solve this problem?

```
@section head
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
//skip
    </script>
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populate a Razor Section From a Partial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355427/populate-a-razor-section-from-a-partial)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only call RenderSection between two Views/Layouts that are directly related. From what you say it looks like your page structure is something like:

UploadForm (section defined here) -> UnknownView -> _Layout (RenderSection called here)

In this situation you would need to essentially redefine and render the section in your View in the middle.

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/12/15/razor-nested-layouts-and-redefined-sections.aspx for a clearer explanation