# Can I create a controller in a common assembly which will be accessible by any assmbly which references it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, embedded-resource, code-reuse

I have a common assembly where I put a lot of my helper functions etc.  I want to create a common `EmbeddedResourceController` (kind of like WebResource.axd was for WebForms) which all my HTML helpers can use to embed and display their scripts and styles.  The problem is, I need to be able to create an include path from my HTML helper code in a project agnostic way (ie without knowing any of the routing/controller rules in that project).

Ideally, I want to create an include like `<script type="text/javascript" src="/EmbeddedResource/myJsScript.js"></script>` from the helper code and have it work in every project that uses my common dll.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can just use this EmbeddedResource controller as a base for a controller in each of your projects:

```
EmbeddedResourceController : EmbeddedResourceBase
```

Where EmbeddedResourceBase lives in your common dll

Comment: I was hoping to do it without needing to add anything to the individual projects.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use an HTML helper extension.  Take a look at **Mr Bell's** answer in the following question [Populate a Razor Section From a Partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355427/populate-a-razor-section-from-a-partial)