# Can I use a Nancy razor @section inside an @Html.Partial(..)?

Tags: razor, nancy

I am successfully using the Nancy Razor engine. I have a `_Master.cshtml` Layout which defines a  razor `@section` for my javascript and others for my `@Html.Partial()` and CSS files.

This all works fine.

**Edit 1**
See here for more useful info including a neat extension method that fixes the problem:

- [Populate a Razor Section From a Partial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5355427/776476)

**_Master Layout**

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<dynamic>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        //Head stuff
        @RenderSection("CSS", required: false)
    </head>
    <body>
        //Body Stuff
        @RenderBody()
        @RenderSection("Partial", required: false)
        @RenderSection("JS", required: false)
    </body> 
</html>
```

**A Example View**

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<dynamic>
@{
    Layout = "_Master.cshtml";
}

// View HTML

@section Partial{
    @Html.Partial("Modal/FindWizard")
}

@section JS{
    <script src="/Scripts/Coffee/example.view.min.js"> </script>
}
```

You can see from the Example View above that I have included a `Partial` called *FindWizard*. I would like this file to also take advantage of the razor sections defined in the _Master Layout.

Something like this:

**FindWizard Partial with @sections**

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<dynamic>

<div>
    //.. Wizard HTML
</div>

@section CSS{
    <link href="/Content/css/bootstrap-wizard.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}

@section JS{
    <script src="/Scripts/min/bootstrap-wizard.min.js"></script>
}
```

I have tried this but I cannot get the razor @sections from the Partial file to render into the final response.

Is this technique possible? Maybe its a plain *bad idea* as it may lead to duplicate js files being included if a Partial is re-used in the same view?

Thanks

Comment: This is a limitation of Razor (not Nancy's) that you cannot have section inside partial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355427/populate-a-razor-section-from-a-partial

Comment: Is that because its a bad idea or is it just an oversight? I know that nancy recently started using a custom version of the razor engine so maybe this limitation can be removed.

Comment: We're not using a custom version, just a custom build of it for licensing reasons, we haven't touched the code.