# Generate meta Keywords and meta Description in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to render meta keywords and meta description in asp.net mvc4. 
In the _layout.cshtml I add optional section:

```
@RenderSection("Header", required: false)
```

and I define meta tags on any content page using @section:

```
 @section Header {
<meta name="description" content="This is test text"> }
```

But when i run and view source in html then it not persists meta tag.
Any ideas for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I switched to used `ViewBag`. 
In the layout page:

```
<meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.Description" />
<meta name="keywords" content="@ViewBag.Keywords" />
```

In the content page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Description = "this is test meta description";
    ViewBag.Keywords = "Test1, Test2, Test3";
}
```

It's work.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're defining the `@section Header{}` from within another Partial View? If so this isn't possible by design, but frustratingly doesn't throw any errors.

[Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355427/populate-a-razor-section-from-a-partial) that has some options to help you work around your issue.