# Can't render section with script in a partial view in Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've seen a [cool gadget](https://www.revolvermaps.com/?target=setupminigl) and I want to use it on my page. I've chosen all the options and they produced a JS that I'm supposed to execute from my site.

Since I'm using Razor, I need to render it as a section so I've added one. However, as I attempted to render it, I got error message telling me that:

> The file "~/Views/Home/EyeCandy.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderSection" method.

So I've googled and found a bunch of articles explaining how to resolve it. The best one (after a few hours) is [this particular reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12312678/1525840). However, I just can't wire my head around it and get confused.

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Default.cshtml"; }
@model List<Donkey>
<h1>List of the eye candies.</h1>

@RenderSection("Footie", false)
@section Footie { <script src="@Url.Content("...")" 
                   async="async" 
                   type="text/javascript"></script> }
```

In the linked reply, there are three files.

1. *_PartialScripts.cshtml*, which I don't have and will need to add populating it from the script tag in my section *Footie*.
2. *_Partial.cshtml*, which is my current view called *EyeCandy.cshtml*.
3. The unnamed code snippet, which I understand corresponds to my *_Default.cshtml* layout.

Now, in my head, it doesn't make sense, because the point is to keep the script out of the layout and limit its scope to the one view where I test my eye candies. I'm sure I'm just too slow to get it at this stage but if someone, pretty-pretty please, points out what I missunderstood, I'll be so happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the `@RenderSection("Footie", false)` in your layout, not in your specific view.

So add this to your `~/Views/Shared/_Default.cshtml`

```
@RenderSection("Footie", false)
```

And in your specific view, you can execute your custom code, which is wrapped inside the Footie `section`

```
@section Footie { 
  <script src="@Url.Content("...")" async="async" type="text/javascript"></script> 
}
```

Comment: Okay. So the rendering went just above the end of body and the section declaration went to the view, at the bottom. When I runt the script saying *alert("Shyju awesome");* it displays, so I guess the question's answered. Now, when I attempt doing the same with the globe-script, I get nothing on the screen but pasted URL in the FF actually gets me a function. Is it something you see obvious? If not, I'll another question, instead. This one's been definitely answered.

Comment: I posted an answer to your other question.