# Nested _ViewStart ignoring Layout setting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my Views root folder I have _ViewStart.cshtml, which has:

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
Page.Title = "Using Root ViewStart!";
}
```

Then in a nested Views\ProjectCharter folder, I have another _ViewStart.cshtml, which looks like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ProjectLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Using Nested ViewStart!";
}
```

(note that both the _Layout.cshtml and the _ProjectLayout.cshtml file are in the same folder, called Views\Shared).

The problem I'm having is that the views in my Views\ProjectCharter folder are NOT using the _ProjectLayout.cshtml Layout...instead they are still using the root _Layout.cshtml (even though they are correctly picking up the "Using Nested ViewStart" title).

What's interesting is that if I change my ActionMethod to return the View using

```
return View("Create","~/Views/Shared/_ProjectLayout.cshtml",newProjectCharter);
```

instead of just

```
return View(newProjectCharter);
```

then the view does indeed use the _ProjectCharterLayout.cshtml layout.  Any idea what I am missing? I don't want to have to change all my ActionMethods to use this more verbose overload.

Comment: Just thinking out loud but both Layout pages are well formed and have correct namespaces?

Comment: Yup.  As indicated, it works when I use the more verbose overload of return View(). If there were a problem with namespacing or well-formedness, using the more verbose overload also would not work.

Comment: Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161380/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-in-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-viewstart-file). It seems an issue on MVC3 :/ but this guy has a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your post you are referring to _ProjectLayout.cshtml being in "

### Views\   'PROJECTCHARTER'

but in the code you are saying that it is in the shared folder:

### Layout = "~/Views/ 'SHARED' /_ProjectLayout.cshtml";

Hope that will sort it out

Comment: Nope, sorry for not being clear on this...but both the _Layout.cshtml and the _ProjectLayout.cshtml file are in the same folder, called Views\Shared; I'll edit my post to make this clear.

Comment: In the pages that you use in the ProjectCharter controller cant you just instead of adding a viewstart there just at the top of each .cshtml page add the layout manualy? That is to add `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ProjectLayout.cshtml";` to the top of each page

Comment: Well yes I could, but that requires a change to each view - going against the DRY principle.

Comment: See if this posts helps you `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161380/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-in-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-viewstart-file`

Comment: Yup, I read through that question b4 I posted mine.  It's actually from that question where I got the hint to try the overload of the return View() method that I mention in my question.