# How to set layout from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there a way to set the layout from the controller?

have tried:

```
ViewData["Layout"] = "..."
return View("view", Model);
```

I know it will sound odd with some people....

Answer (score 38, accepted):

View method has overload to set its master layout something like this

```
return View ("NameOfView",masterName:"viewName");
```

Answer (score 12):

In action method you can use  **MasterName** property in **ViewResult** class to change layout page.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var myView = View();
            myView.MasterName = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml"; 
            return myView;
        }
```

Comment: Always great to see different flavors.

Answer (score 8):

Using your code, you could put this in your View:

```
@ {
    Layout = ViewData["Layout"];
}
```

Comment: He's already set the ViewData["Layout"] in his code, this is what he needs to add to the view to make it work but I see what you're saying.

Comment: Works perfectly for me, Dotnet Core MVC doesn't have the property of MasterName on the view so I couldn't set that. I tweaked this code to be slightly more robust. Layout = (ViewData["Layout"] as String) ?? "_Layout";

Answer (score 7):

Daren Dimitrov has a very nice answer on this one with Attributes:

[How do I specify different Layouts in the ASP.NET MVC 3 razor ViewStart file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161380/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-in-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-viewstart-file)

Answer (score 4):

In the controller you can set a masterpage like this. I'm using MVC 5.2

```
return View("ViewName", "MasterPageName", model)
```

Answer (score -3):

If you have a _ViewStart.cshtml file in your Views directory, you can automatically set the layout for all views within the same folder (and sub-folders):

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: The question was about how to set it from the controller.

Comment: Fair enough, misread the question :). In that case, you could use Rob's suggestion above.

Comment: @JamesSimm why not delete this answer, thereby simultaneously removing an incorrect answer and making your reputation higher?