# How to set layout from controller in .NET Core 3

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Currently, I am upgrading .NET MVC to .NET Core MVC. In MVC we are using a method like below so I need to keep that logic and it's used in lots of places. so can you help to find a way to set the Layout page from .NET Core Controller?

`return View ("NameOfView",masterName:"viewName");`
[How to set layout from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205098/how-to-set-layout-from-controller)

Answer (score 0):

You could find the difference of ViewResult between asp.net and asp.net core
Asp.Net Core
[image]
Asp.Net
[image]

[image]

[image]
there's no method supplied for your to set layout in controller the sameway with which you set masterpage in asp.net controller

You could set masterpage in your view Like:

```
@{
    Layout = "_myLayoutPage";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, we can set it in _ViewStart file using ViewData.

[image]