# MVC4 have a view working as a layout/masterpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nested-forms

As Im building sort of a window/tool setup in MVC4 Im wondering is it possible to do like a  `@Html.Partial("_PartialToolWindow")` In a page including all the tools to be loaded.
And then have this `_PartialToolWindow` load a defalut html template that should surround this code that the `_PartialToolWindow` contains?

For example...

```
<div class='boarder'>
     <div class='innerBorder'>
          --HERE IS THE SPECIFIC CONTENS--
     </div>
</div>
```

This  `_PartialToolWindow` should have loaded this `border` and `innerBorder` to surrond its own HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13089489/205859) in your layout.

_Layout.cshtml

```
<div class='boarder'>
     <div class='innerBorder'>
          @RenderSection("PartialToolWindow")
     </div>
</div>
```

Then you will be able to load specific content in your views:

```
@section PartialToolWindow
{
    <span>content</span>
}
```