# Render a javascript file in all views in MVC in asp

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to render `javascript` in all views .this java file is for `datetimepicker` that i use in my views :

```
    <script>
               Calendar.setup({
                   inputField: 'date_input',
                   button: 'date_btn',
                   ifFormat: '%Y/%m/%d',
                   dateType: 'jalali'
               });
</script>
```

I have to put in every views this script ,but it's not a good idea!!!so i put this script in header of layout page ,but i got this error when my pages is refreshed :

[image]

So where should i put this script to avoid this error ????

best regards .

any ideas will be appreciated .

Comment: Learn about [sections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089489/asp-net-mvc-explanation-of-section) in MVC views. If its in the `header` but not wrapped in `document.Ready` then it runs before the html elements are created

Comment: @StephenMuecke where should i put this code to render after html ?

Comment: Scripts should ideally be immediately before the closing `</body>` tag

Comment: i put after </body> but again same error

Comment: _after_ is not the same as _immediately before_! What is `Calendar.setup`?

Comment: No matter where you place it, the code will execute immediately as there is no $(document).ready(). It will be nice if you include a sample page as well with a bit more code