# Page.Header.Controls.Add(css) for MVC razor view

Tags: c#

Hi I am having an issue adding addition css styling to an existing class when the page loadsfor MVC razor view engine.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Page.Header` property (and the `Page` class as a whole) is a WebForms concept and not available in the Razor.  You can add additional elements to the `head` of a page using sections or even the `ViewBag`.

[ASP.NET MVC explanation of @section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089489/asp-net-mvc-explanation-of-section)