# am getting error "following sections have been defined but have not been rendered"

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

am getting above error
**"following sections have been defined but have not been rendered"**

whenever I try to add style by razor calling syntax.

```
@section Styles {
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/plugins/iCheck/iCheckStyles")
}
```

Am new to MVC5 Razor, so please can any one help ?

Comment: Does you layout include `@RenderSection("styles", false)`?

Comment: no not at all, should I add it ?

Comment: Yes. That acts as a placeholder for the content defined the views `@section styles {` - typically, for styles, you would place it in the layout's `<head>` tags

Comment: what this function will do ? can you explain please ? so I can use it next time properly. Thanks @StephenMuecke

Comment: Have a look at [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor) and also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089489/asp-net-mvc-explanation-of-section)

Comment: ok got it but false statement will do in it.

Comment: If you specify `false` as the second parameter, it means that a view that uses the layout does not need to have `@section styles { ..` defined (its optional). Otherwise you need to use `@if (IsSectionDefined("styles ")) { @section styles {` to check the view has the section (or an exception will be thrown if the view does not have `@section styles { ..`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `@section Styles`, you layout being used by the view must include

```
@RenderSection("styles", false)
```

`@RenderSection` acts as a placeholder in the layout to render any content that has been defined in in the section. In your case in means that the css files defined in the `iCheckStyles` bundle will be rendered at the point in the view where `@RenderSection` is declared. For css files, this would typically be in the `<head>` tags immediately before `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")`

Note the second parameter defines whether the view requires a `@section Styles { ... }`. If the value is `false`, then `@section Styles` is optional, other wise the view must include `@section Styles` or an exception will be thrown.