# Require a JavaScript module inside a single Phoenix template

Tags: javascript, html, phoenix-framework

What is the standard method to require a defined JavaScript module inside of a single Phoenix Template?

I don't want the module required anywhere but inside this one template.

Here is a snippet of the files I am using.

### web/static/js/trend_chart.js

```js
let TrendChart = {
  //... some JS module code here
}
```

### web/templates/layout/app.html.eex

This has the standard app load/require.

```
...

<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>

<script>require("web/static/js/app")</script>

...
```

### web/templates/page/index.html.eex

```html
<!-- what do i put in this template to require / load the TrendChart module code? -->
<!-- i don't want it required globally, so i don't want to put it in the app.html.eex file -->
```

### Update #1

I'm really looking for a way to have two `@inner` blocks in the main layout. One for the content, and one for additional JavaScript items to be loaded *after* the content.

Something like [sections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13089574/4552290) in ASP.NET MVC. (I know, I know!)

So the `app.html.eex` would end up something like this:

```
...
@inner
...

<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
<script>require("web/static/js/app")</script>

*something here to load page/template specific javascript*
```

Comment: So, I have this working by putting the `<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>` before the `@inner` so I can use the loaded JS libs within the individual page template. I was hoping there was another way to append JS after the `@inner` for a specific page.

Comment: @toraritte this link is dead. probably it's better to include the relevant piece of code here the next time, than an external link alone.

Comment: [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170123021546/https://blog.diacode.com/page-specific-javascript-in-phoenix-framework-pt-1) was the answer for me.

Comment: thanks. no need to remove your original comment tho - it might confuse others.

Answer (score 8):

You can save the file to `web/static/assets/trend_chart.js` then it will be copied to `priv/static/trend_chart.js` and available from `<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/trend_chart.js") %>"></script>`.

All files saved to the `web/static/assets` directory are directly copied to `priv/static` without going through the build phase.

Comment: The caveat with this approach is you don't get minification. The other approach would be to set up a rule like here https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/10b989dda6fb2ac38d3e876e32f107294475a156/installer/templates/static/brunch/brunch-config.js#L10 that vendors the single to the same name as itself.

Comment: That part works fine. I guess what I'm really wondering is if there is any way to have another `@inner` in the layout that could be placed in the layout after the main content and the normal script loading (app.js). Something like  [this MVC solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13089574/4552290).