# Why does my ASP .NET MVC 5 Razor View not Recognize My Javascript fuction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using a Modal Bootstrap Class to have a user fill out some forms and then have a "complete" button at the end to submit the answers to the forms:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitCallScriptBtn" onclick="submitInitialCallScript(this);" 
      data-ptKey="@Model.Patient.PtKey" data-assignedTaskKey="@Model.Tasks[0].TassKey" 
      class="btn btn-primary">Complete Initial Call</button>
```

So, when a user clicks the submit button, I want to call a JavaScript function from a separate JavaScript File called 'PatientSearch.js':

```
function submitInitialCallScript(elem) {
    console.log("This Method is running");
    var e = document.getElementById("communication");
    var eResponse = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    var ptKey = $(elem).data('ptKey');
    var assignedTasakKey = $(elem).data('assignedTaskKey');


    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text',
        url: '~/PatientController/SubmitInitialCallScript',
        data: {
            ptKey: ptKey,
            tass_Key: assignedTaskKey,
            question1: $("input[name=goodtime]:checked").val(),
            question2: $("input[name=startedDevice]:checked").val(),
            question3: $("input[name=driver]:checked").val(),
            question3a: $("input[name=comfort]:checked").val(),
            question4: $("#concerns").val(),
            question5: $("input[name=occupation]:checked").val(),
            question6: $("input[name=appointmentscheduled]:checked").val(),
            question6a: $("#doctor").val(),
            question6b: $("#appointDate").val(),
            question7: $("input[name=selfTracking]:checked").val(),
            question8: $("input[name=understand]:checked").val(),
            question9: eResponse,
            question10: $("#otherQuestions").val()

        }, success(data) {
            if (data == "true")
                window.location.assign("~/Controllers/Patient/Index");
            else
                alert("Error Submitting");

        }, failure(data) {
            alert("Error Submitting")
        }
    })
```

However, I can not get my JavaScript Method to run.  When I click my button, nothing happens..even though the files are linked up correctly:

[image: JavaScript being called from the correct Folder]

Is there something wrong I am doing?  Is there a different way to call JavaScript Method and I am doing it incorrectly?

EDIT:

Here are some screenshots of the Web ToolKit Errors:

[image: There is no link to the file when the project is running]

Here you see PatientSearch.js not even in the file structure even though it is the same you see in Visual Studio.

[image: Here you see the Javascript File not even in the file structure of the project]

Comment: is it showing in developer tools sources tab?

Comment: @JAG If you mean, does the script tag show up in Dev Tools, yes it does.

Comment: Do you see any error in Dev tools Console when you click on the button?

Comment: not just the script tag, check the actual file is loaded or not from Sources tab or Network tab

Comment: Is your button inside a `<form>`?

Comment: @JAG Actually no.. Which is surprising.  Any idea why it would not be there?

Comment: @MattSpinks Nope, button is just within a bunch of <div> tags.

Comment: looks like `Sitewide.js` loading fine, so use the same method to load `PatientSearch.js`. it may be issue with relative path `src="~/..`

Comment: @JAG Yeah, I am using MVC, and including the Javascript in the <head> of my "_Layout.cshtml" solved the issue...

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong, but a few bad practices. 1). The `@model` declaration should be the first line. 2) You should avoid hardcoded app-relative URLs, i.e. `~/`. Instead, use something like `Url.Content("~/JavaScript/PatientSearch.js")`, which will ensure that the URL is truly evaluated. App-relative URLs are actually not supported by browsers. Razor *should* catch the hardcoded app-relative URL and change it for you, but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: @ChrisPratt You know, I think this is exactly the issue I am having right now.  Let me verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using ASP .NET MVC 5.  It seems that including the PatientSearch.js `<script>` within the `<head>` tag of my "_Layout.cshtml" allowed the function to get recognized where the particular View is not for some reason.  Not really a "solution" but it did solve the reason why I had opened this question.

Comment: Go over the comment about restructuring _how_ you add your scripts in the page. You're code seems to show that you are mixing scripts with content. You can leverage [`@sections`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13089489/304683) for that. Hth.