# How do I make one View have different content from what's specified in its layout?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Suppose I have many views, each displaying very similar content. Each view uses the same _Layout as defined in _ViewStart.

My _Layout might look like this:

```
<html>
<!-- some html -->
@ViewBag.SomeViewBagFun
<!-- more html -->
@RenderBody
<!-- more html -->
@SpecialFunction()
</html>

Helper SpecialFunction()
@<a href="/">Linky</a>
@<!-- complex HTML -->
End Helper
```

Suppose 90% of my pages use the default `SpecialFunction()` as defined in the layout, but occasionally some views want a different `SpecialFunction()`.

One way to resolve this is to use `ViewBag` and send each view content that way, but `SpecialFunction()` contains complex HTML and I want to use razor views.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I believe this question is more suited for StackOverflow. It should be migrated.

Comment: Damn. I put it here thinking it's more of a concept question rather than something overly specific. Thanks, I've reported it for migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use a Section and when you render it make it *NOT* required.

See ScottGu's blog for some details: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the layout in the actual `View`, as such,

```
@{
    Layout = "/address/to/your/different/layout.cshtml"
}
```

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161380/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-in-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-viewstart-file) for further info.

Comment: But in my example, the View still wants to use the _Layout (like all other views), just change a particular section of the layout. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

OP here.

It's been a while since I used ASP.NET MVC & Razor. I forgot about **Sections**. I feel silly ^^

Solution:

`_Layout`

```html
<html>
<!-- some html -->
@ViewBag.SomeViewBagFun
<!-- more html -->
@RenderBody
<!-- more html -->
@If IsSectionDefined("SpecialFunction") Then
    @RenderSection("SpecialFunction", False)
Else
    @SpecialFunction()
End If

</html>

Helper SpecialFunction()
@<a href="/">Linky</a>
@<!-- complex HTML -->
End Helper
```

`Another View`

```html
Section SpecialFunction
<p>Very different HTML!</p>
End Section
```

Comment: I believe as you have coded it in your sample, the Section is required.  Unless your section is marked as "required: false" it will be expected in EVERY view.

Comment: Good point. Although if I specify the Section in the _Layout, won't it always be there unless it's overridden in a View?

Comment: Well. Yeah, but that sort of defeats the point. the idea with sections is that you render" conditionally and then you only add them to the view when you want to see/use them.  Think of it like an optional parameter in a method.

Comment: I've updated my code to be more explicit about what's going on. Does it make more sense now? I want it so that the section has a default unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition to your viewbag and based on the value the layout would execute specialFfunction or someOtherFunction [Scott Guthrie gives a great example of this technique in his blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)