# how can i set layout to null in action filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it posible to set the layout to null in action filter? For example

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

I want to render some action with

```
@Html.Action("someaction")
```

it works for now.

But i want to use this action in 2 modes : like child and like master for different situations. I can set Layout to null in view for this

view:

```
@{
   if(condtition)
   {
        Layout = null;
   }
}
```

But i want to find more elegant way :)

Like:

action without partial

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

and in filter set the layout to null if action is child

```
 public class LayoutFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
           if(filterContext.IsChildAction)
           {
               //set the layout to NULL here!

           }
        }
    }
```

It is posible? Any ideas?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate.

See [accepted answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161380/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-in-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-viewstart-file)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you have overriden the `OnActionExecuting` event but this happens way too early. The actions hasn't even executed yet nor returned an ActionResult and you are already attempting to set its Layout.

Wait for it to complete, by overriding the `OnActionExecuted` event, retrieve the Result property from the `filterContext` and if it is a `ViewResult` set its `MasterName` property to null:

```
public class LayoutFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.MasterName = null;
        }
    }
}
```