# Use a different layout inside iframe for asp.net mvc views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I have some controller action that can be accessed via an iframe that is launched in some view. This controller action can also be accessed via the website in it's normal fashion. I have implemented the controller so that when the `?iframe=true` parameter is in the URL it behaves differently.

So the controller action looks like:

```
public ActionResult Index(bool? iframe=null){

    //...some controller logic...

    if(iframe==true){
        ViewBag.InIFrame = true;
    }
    return View("Index", model)
}
```

Then the View will load a different layout depending on whether the `ViewBag.InIFrame` is set.

But now I would need to do this for every controller action where it is feasible that the user could navigate to from within the iframe. Is there a better way I could do this? I thought of using a session variable that is set when the user is navigated to the first expected page within the iframe, but if the user navigates to the some pages of the site in a different tab (not in an iframe) it will load the layout for when we are in an iframe.

Any ideas or should I just suck it up and make each controller action do the same check for `iframe` being a supplied parameter?

Comment: Define a global variable in `_Layout` and make decision according its changes perhaps by an `if`.

Comment: rather doing at action level , you can do that on filter level or if for a single controller then at controller level , there you can check for querystring parameter and then set viewdata also

Comment: add your implementation like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17796568/1018054