# Having two master pages in mvc 3 application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a ***MVC*** application that exist at the moment using a `_MainLayoutPage` for its *Master Page*.

I want to create another *Master Page* for a different purpose. I will be creating a new controller as well.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161380/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-in-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-viewstart-file

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is in your Action Method, set a Viewbag property for your Layout

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ViewBag.Layout= "~/Views/Shared/layout2.cshtml";
```

In your View, set the layout property

```
@{
    Layout = @ViewBag.Layout;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In _ViewStart.cshtml, put this:

```
    @{
        try {
            Layout = "~/Views/" + ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] + "/_Layout.cshtml";
        }
        catch {
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        }
    }
```

And then you can put a controller specific `_Layout.cshtml` in your controller folders, like

- `~/Views/User/_Layout.cshtml` for a controller named `UserController`
- `~/Views/Account/_Layout.cshtml` for a controller named `AccountController`

And because of the try/catch, it will fall back to the '~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml' layout if one is not defined for a specific controller.