# How to call view as full page (ignoring render body)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a regular application _Layout.cshtml and @RenderBody() to render all views inside, but only for the Login view need to be render as full page not inside @RenderBody().

Regards

Comment: Do you need just specify a different layout? Then see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5161380/67392

Comment: In this way it got a error for @RenderBody(), I dont need a @RenderBody() in the other layout, it will be only a login screen, after user is logged it should back to the other layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `Layout` property to `null` at the beginning of your view.

So, your `Login.cshtml` file should start with:

```
@model YourModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may not want to have no layout for your view.  You probably want a custom layout (something like _LayoutFullPage.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>SOMETHING HERE ALONG WITH OTHER HEAD ATTRIBUTES</title>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody() 
</body>
</html>
```

and then use that layout in the view with

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutFullPage.cshtml";
}
```

Other options are to set the view as null in the cshtml (as suggested by RePierre) or to call `return PartialView(model);` within your controller.