# Setting a new landing page in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor, configuration, middleware

I need to set a new landing page for my application. For now it is landing on the standard Index.cshtml inside of the Home folder inside of the Views folder. I want my new landing page to be from this directory:

**Views/Welcome/Index.cshtml**

The error I'm getting says:
**InvalidOperationException: RenderBody has not been called for the page at '/Views/Welcome/Index.cshtml'. To ignore call IgnoreBody();**

I have made the following changes so far in my startup.cs file:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
            {
                o.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
                o.ViewLocationForms.Add("/Views/Welcome/Index" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
            });
        }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Welcome}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Welcome");
        }
```

My View:

```
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

//html
//jQuery
```

I haven't found any resources online on how to accomplish this when using MVC.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Redirect to other view

If you want to return different `view` in a simply way, you could try redirecting to other view in `Home/Index`.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            //return View();
            return View("~/Views/Welcome/Index.cshtml");
        }
 }
```

> Layout

As for the layout, `_ViewStart.cshtml`(`/Pages/Shared`) are run before every full view (not layouts, and not partial views).

_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

> Render JS

In the code below, you define the scripts section and render scripts inside the section.

Index.cshtml

```
 @RenderSection("Scripts", required: true)
```

_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml

```
 @section Scripts {
   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/js1.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/js2.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/js3.js"></script>
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Calling my new page from the HomeController solved everything. No need to modify any other files.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution. I added Layout = null to my view (the new landing page), but it removed all of my css. I then added the paths to my css libraries inside of this file. It seems to work, but I am still open to any suggestions (if any) on how to improve any of this code. Thanks!

This is how I found my solution: [Stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758530/how-to-call-view-as-full-page-ignoring-render-body)