# Creating custom URL routing that separates admin section from other sections of a website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I'd like to create a custom URL routing that has a constant path at ASP.NET MVC 5 project.
For example I'd like to have "[www.mysite/admin/controller/action/](http://www.mysite/admin/controller/action/)" that `admin` is a constant.Also I have some routes apart from this.

After that I'd like to define a policy for while entered `admin/controller/action/` in browser, directed to the admin panel, else if `admin/` does not exist in URL, directed to the regular page.
For this goal, I've written some codes in `_ViewStart.cshtml` but needs some reforms.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Tag",
           url: "Tags/{tag}/{page}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Article", action = "Index", tag = (string)null, id = UrlParameter.Optional, page = @"/d" }
           );

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Tags",
          url: "Tags/",
          defaults: new { controller = "Tag", action = "Index" }
          );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "Page{page}",
            new { Controller = "Article", action = "Index" },
            new { page = @"/d" }
            );
}
```

_ViewStart.cshtml:

```
@{
   if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
   {
       // ??? need some codes for directing just to the /admin part
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
   }
   else
   {
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an Admin [Area](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC) in your MVC application, and this will have it's own routing.  Take a look at this link here for help with [*Using Areas*](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/601504/Using-areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC-to-organize-a-project).  Your route may look like this...

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: Many thanks.For managing the layouts I've used @Darin Dimitrov's solution. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5161384/1817640