# How to replace current layout at runtime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a little app (asp.net mvc).
I have a question: in my project i have a layout - _layout.chtml,
It's possible to replace the content with different content that i inject from a file?

For example:
Current _layout.chtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>      
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Now, i want to load new content from a file and replace the current _layout with new content as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
<link href="~/css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>   
    @RenderPage("../Shared/_Header2.cshtml")    
    @RenderBody()
    @RenderPage("../Shared/_Footer2.cshtml")

    <script src="~/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/angular.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

How do i can to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want overwrite your _ViewStart.cshtml you some other ways

`return View ("NameOfView",masterName:"viewName");`

Or
store your layout in viewData like

```
//in controller
ViewData["Layout"]="your layout path";
//in _ViewStart.cshtml
Layout = ViewData["Layout"];
```

Or you can create a custom attribiute and set your layout name in it like

```
[LayoutInjecter("_PublicLayout")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

for more information check this answer [specify different Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161380/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-in-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-viewstart-file)

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're calling a new controller action at the time where you want to replace your layout. If so, then one of the following would do the trick;

First off you can put a `_ViewStart.cshtml` file in your `\Views\` folder to override the default layout as seen below.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

From here you can add another `_ViewStart.cshtml` file in `\Views\User` to override the default layout for all your `\User\` views.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UserLayout.cshtml";
}
```

You can also specify the above in a view, e.g. for `\Views\User\Index.cshtml`.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UserIndexLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Or you can specify the layout when returning the view in the controller;

```
return View("Index", "~/Views/Shared/_UserLayout.cshtml", someViewModel);
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not help for me, it's not static layout, it can be replace sometimes, and i need to replace the content..

Comment: So you're trying to upload a new _Layout.cshtml file at runtime, and want the page to refresh using that layout instead of the site's default? The solution I provided is not just for static content, but it would require a set of predefined layouts.