# How to remove an HTML element from the Layout for a 1 particular page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and am wondering what I should be doing if I my `_Layout.cshtml` has an element

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
   ...
</div>
```

that I don't want generated for a particular page with controller `SomePageController.cs` and view `SomePage.cshtml`. Do I just wrap that piece of HTML in an `if` statement like

```
@if(not on SomePage) {
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
       ...
    </div>
}
```

or is there a more proper way?

Answer (score 4):

I usually use a magic string in ViewBag for this. I set it in my controller (or you can do it in the top of the view, if you wish).

```
ViewBag.HideNavBar = true;
```

in the _Layout:

```
@if(ViewBag.HideNavBar == null) {
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
       ...
    </div>
}
```

I use this strategy to pass options into the layout (such as datepicker options) all the time.

Comment: By "in the view", are you referring to the view for that particular page or the _Layout?

Answer (score 1):

Give the single page that doesn't need that `<div>` a [different Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161380/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-in-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-viewstart-file):

```
@model Foo
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutWithoutNavigation.cshtml";
}

<!-- rest of HTML -->
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it multiple way

1: Simple trick.. just use If condition and get the route name from Query string and match it with your route .

2: use two different layouts. one with that HTML part and one without HTML part.
and when creating view just specify the layout without HTML.

3: Use ViewBag / tempData

**Approaches:**

***First:***

```
if(Request.QueryString["routeName"] != "MyRoute" )
{
   //Render HTML Part
}
```

***second:***

```
@{
 layout = "~/shared/LayoutWithoutHTML.cshtml";
}
```

***Third***

> in your Controller where you want to hide HTML

viewBag.HTMLCheck = true;

> In your View

```
if(viewBag.HTMLCheck != true)
{
  // Html Part
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems like an appropriate way to go about it - ideally though, if it's not going to be on every page, the pages without that section should use a different Layout.