# Inherited layout in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, nested

I have default layout _Layout.cshtml for the most pages. However for some group of pages I would like to have slightly modified default layout. I know I could just copy that file a modified it a bit, but it would mean to duplicate the code and maintain two layout with 99% of same code.

I would like to inherit the layout from the default like this:

LayoutInherited.cshtml:

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
ViewBag.BodyContentClassSpecial = "";

@section header{
<style>
    #body-content {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
```

}

It is possible to do something like this?

Comment: yep, you can have as many layout pages in an application, but one layout page per page. :-)  this answer might help you in detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161380/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-in-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-viewstart-file

Comment: This is not I am asking about. I just want to inherit one layout from the other, because only few variables and one section is different.

Comment: you can include a file in another , because it is treated as html. <div w3-include-html="content.html"></div> but i Haven;t tried this though .

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, layout inheritance is possible. Essentially, you're just creating a layout that itself utilizes a layout, since layouts are just views, there's no issues with that.

You pretty much do it exactly as you described:

**_SubLayout.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@RenderBody()
```

A few things to keep in mind:

1. The content of the sub-layout will be placed where you have `@RenderBody` in your base layout, just as the content of a view would be. Your sub-layout still needs its own `@RenderBody` to determine where the content of the view that utilizes it should be placed.
2. Any sections defined as required in your base layout *must* be implemented in your sub-layout or Razor will raise an exception, just as if your view did not implement the section. For example:

   **_Layout.cshtml**

   ```
   @RenderSection("Foo", required: true)
   ```

   **_SubLayout.cshtml**

   ```
   @section Foo
   {
       <p>Foo</p>
   }
   ```
3. If your view needs to be able to implement a section (required or not), the sub-layout must define it. For example, in the code above, any view using `_SubLayout.cshtml` would not be able to define a `Foo` section, because it would no longer exist. An exception would be raised if you tried. In order to allow that view to define that section you would have to do something like the following:

   **_SubLayout.cshtml**

   ```
   @section Foo
   {
       @RenderSection("Foo", required: true)
   }
   ```

   This defines the section for the purpose of the base layout and then allows the section to be defined by any view that uses this sub layout.

There's actually a post on my blog that goes into all this in much greater detail if you need it: http://cpratt.co/how-to-change-the-default-asp-net-mvc-themet/

Comment: the link is a nice guide to basic function of razor. Absolutely suggested for beginners