# Razor template engine - blocks and inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Coming from the PHP world, I use Twig for templating. Twig supports inheritance using the extend and block features:

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/extends.html

Is there any way to do something similar in Razor (ASP.NET Core MVC)?

Losing this feature when moving to ASP.NET Core MVC feels like losing a limb!

Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain the exact functionality you need. Just mentioning "inheritance" doesn't really help, as that is ambiguous. What end result do you need? Do you need reusable, callable components, for example?

Comment: Please read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960821/inherited-layout-in-asp-net-mvc