# In C#.Net, what code can I use in ViewStart.cshtml to select various _Layout.cshtml for each MyPage.cshtml?

Tags: c#, inheritance, layout

I have various cshtml pages where I want different `_Layout.cshtml` files to apply. I know that the MVC library uses `_ViewStart.cshtml`, but I have not yet found examples of code that will allow me to select with `_Layout` is applied to which page.

Comment: whats wrong with using Layout = "xxxx" at the beginning of your cshtml file

Comment: check out this question, I think it should answer yours:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161380/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-in-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-viewstart-file

Comment: @MykhailoSeniutovych—yep—that'll do it.

Comment: After a little digging, I also found: http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/different-ways-of-rendering-layouts-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: @Larry You can also use `@{ Layout = null; }` in your view to not apply any layouts to your view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I specify different Layouts in the ASP.NET MVC 3 razor ViewStart file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161380/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-in-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-viewstart-file)