# How to redirect user to another page instead of _Layout View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Sorry to ask that kind of question but I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and trying to implement this project but I have this problem.

I'm using a different layout page instead of the default one with some links in it for "Register" and "Login" using ASP.NET Identity. So when the user logs in or registers, I want to redirect him to another page other than that layout.. but I can't figure it out.

I tried random solution on the internet, using

```
Context.Response.Redirect(location)
```

in the layout page if the user is signed in using the `SignInManager` but after redirecting it to that new page in the location, when I try to go to another location from that page it just gets me back to the location page, like it is stuck to this single page.

Comment: Please see this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161380/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-in-the-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-viewstart-file

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper that is kind of not the problem I have, maybe I explained it in a wrong way. I need to make another _Layout is the default one when the user logs in.. because when I run the web application and log in, it successfully redirect me to another page.. but when I close the application but it is still logged in it redirects me to the default _Layout.. and I designed it to be a like a temp page for guests to ask him to create an account or log in only